# Fields and methods in enum Danger levels

Tags: java

I am given an enum named DangerLevel.

I must add an integer field to store danger levels and match the number with each constant:

HIGH — 3
MEDIUM — 2
LOW — 1
You should also add the instance method getLevel that returns the associated integer number.

After your modifications, the following code should be compiled and work correctly:

```
DangerLevel high = DangerLevel.HIGH;
DangerLevel medium = DangerLevel.MEDIUM;

System.out.println(high.getLevel() > medium.getLevel()); // true
```

here is my code:

```
enum DangerLevel {
    HIGH  (3),  //calls constructor with value 3
    MEDIUM(2),  //calls constructor with value 2
    LOW   (1)   //calls constructor with value 1
    ; // semicolon needed when fields / methods follow


    int levelCode;


    DangerLevel(int levelCode) {
        this.levelCode = levelCode;
    }

    public int getLevel(int levelCode) {
        return this.levelCode = levelCode;
    }
}
```

I get error:

```
Compilation error
Main.java:: error: method getLevel in enum DangerLevel cannot be applied to given types;
        System.out.println(high.getLevel());
                               ^
  required: int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Comment: Carefully look at your code for `getLevel` and compare it to your method call. Then consider making `levelCode` `final`, because it's a constant.

Comment: You are also breaking the method contract by changing a value in a ```getX()``` method. A ```getX()``` method should only return a value, **never** change a value. That is what a ```setX(value)``` method is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `getLevel` method. You are expecting the parameter `levelCode` to be passed to the function and you are actually updating the levelCode upon method call. However, you only want to return the levelCode. So you should do the following instead to achieve this:

```
public int getLevel(){
        return this.levelCode;  // you could also remove 'this'
    }
```